# Scala addition of double gives different answer

Tags: java, scala, math

i am trying to financial app, where sum of credit and debit is 0

Why this is like this

```
scala> 7595.00-8544.38+949.38
res7: Double = 7.958078640513122E-13
```

but when sorted and added

```
scala> 7595.00+949.38-8544.38
res8: Double = 0.0
```

well the problem is numbers are at random but they always sum upto to **zero**

i did same with **node** and found same results.
what is the problem.

i wrote this function it works

```
def sum(xs: List[Double]): Double = {
    xs match {
      case x :: tail => BigDecimal(x +  sum(tail)).setScale(2,BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble 
      case Nil => 0
    } 
}
```

it's strange though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating point numbers are not exact representations of the underlying values.  This is just a fact of how floating point numbers are encoded in binary.

For more information, check out the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_numbers#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding).

If you want exactness, use [BigDecimal](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.BigDecimal):

```
 scala> BigDecimal(759500,2) - BigDecimal(854438,2) + BigDecimal(94938,2)
 res1: scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.00
```

Comment: Thanks ,i prefer scala> BigDecimal(7595.00) - BigDecimal(8544.38) + BigDecimal(949.38) as the amount can be in one or two decimal

Comment: @ameychavan, don't do that because if you create a BigDouble out of a floating point number, then you might just be creating a BigDouble that already has the rounding error in it.  E.g. `BigDecimal(1.1+2.2)`.

Comment: ,i'm not using double, but transforming right from the string i get from the inputstream

Comment: Uhh, The `8544.38` in `BigDecimal(8544.38)` is a double... But yeah, going from a string is fine.

Answer (score 4):

This is why you should never use floating-point math for money. What you have there is a rounding error.

Comment: thanks,it would be helpful if you add alternatives